# mongodb aggregation of multiple values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying analytics with mongodb , but i am very new at it although i got it working for 1 query i don't think its efficient one , here is my example of my dataset

```
{
_id: ObjectId("54442882fa2e117a55f3458b"),
analytic_num: 185,
createdAt: ISODate("2014-10-19T21:09:22.167Z"),
updatedAt: ISODate("2014-10-19T21:09:22.167Z"),
rawBrowser: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0",
gender: "male",
eventId: "accepted",
type: "member",
relationshipStatus: "Single",
ageRange: "18-25",
uid: "53f79ae6f158168161f04d27",
cid: "54370fa7498a776e1c065120",
education: ["high_school", "professional_degree"],
interestedIn: ["female"],
__v: 0
}
```

here is the query m trying

```
db.analytics.aggregate([{
$match: {
    createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date(2014, 9, 15),
        $lt: new Date(2014, 9, 28)
    }
}
}, {
$project: {
    _id: 0,
    minute: {
        $minute: "$createdAt"
    },
    hour: {
        $hour: "$createdAt"
    }
}
}, {
$group: {
    _id: {
        minute: "$minute",
        hour: "$hour"
    },
    hits: {
        $sum: 1
    }
}
}]);
```

here is the result i am getting

```
{ "_id" : { "minute" : 33, "hour" : 21 }, "hits" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "minute" : 29, "hour" : 21 }, "hits" : 6 }
{ "_id" : { "minute" : 6, "hour" : 22 }, "hits" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "minute" : 9, "hour" : 21 }, "hits" : 1 }
```

everything is fine but i only get hits for every minute of every hour , thats fine if i just want only hits

but i if need to find out hits by type or gender or ageRange  i need to change `$match` query, thats not efficient to run this query for all the attributes by changing `$matvh`

How can i get all the hits for type,gender, angRange in one query 
i want result like this

```
{ "_id" : { "minute" : 33, "hour" : 21 }, "hits" : 30, "member" :2 "single": 12 ,"male" :12 }
{ "_id" : { "minute" : 34, "hour" : 21 }, "hits" : 50, "member" :22 "single": 12 ,"male" :12 }
```

Pls help

thanks

Comment: I don't think the result can be got by **aggregate** in one query. For example, value of field **gender** can be male or female; to sum respectively, you have to group them by specifying each as a part of group id. So, you have to group these field one by one at last. Use mapReduce should be able to get the result by `one query`.

Comment: @Wizard you could not be more completely incorrect. I would like to suggest you take a break from trying to answer people here and take some time to observe and learn. Far too many misleading statements coming from your lack of knowledge on the subject. It is not helping people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator. This allows you to evaluate a condition and then make a decision on whether this returns `true|false` to which value you want to return. In this case, whether you want to add an increment to a [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operation or whether you don't:

```js
db.analytics.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "createdAt": {
            "$gte": new Date(2014, 9, 15),
            "$lt": new Date(2014, 9, 28)
        }
    }}, 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "minute": { "$minute": "$createdAt" },
            "hour": { "$hour": "$createdAt" }
        },
        "hits": { "$sum": 1 },
        "member": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$type", "member" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "single": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$relationshipStatus", "single" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "male": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$gender", "male" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
]);
```

So the `$cond` operator is basically a "ternary", or `if..then..else` construct, which evaluates a condition and returns a value based on how that condition was determined, `true|false`. You use it in this way to determine the value returned.

Be careful with date aggregation operators. Maybe what you want here is every minute of every hour, aggregated for all days within that range. But usually people just want the discrete time periods over each day, even by the minute.

Be careful what you ask for, you just might get it.

Comment: hey @Neil i get SyntaxError: Unexpected number can you figure out where it can be

Comment: i got it there was a missing semi colon in $cond

Comment: Hey @Neil i am evaluating your answer it seems exactly what i want , there is just 1 thing i wanted to ask if i have an array e.g Education : ["high_school", "professional_degree" ] , how do select individual hits like high_school , professional_degree as i can't use $eq operator may be i should use $in operator but i get error "exception: invalid operator '$in'" , if i cant use array do you have any other suggestion how i can solve this , thanks